# Python | Jupyter Notebook - NLTK function slow when checking for words

Tags: python, optimization, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to clean up my dataset by using NLTK, but I'm having some trouble, as it is taking ages to complete. I do have a very large dataset of over 20000+ rows of text.

The code that I'm running looks like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
nltk.download('words')
gibberishBody = []

for x in bodyStopWords:
    if x in words.words():
        gibberishBody.append(x)
print(gibberishBody)
```

bodyStopWords is pandas.core.series.Series datatype.

Does anyone have any suggestions to optimize the script for speed?

Comment: Please add a tiny portion of the data in the form of a code snippet @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `words.words()` returns a large list of English words. Checking membership via `in` is slow (linear) for lists. That is, to check if some word `x` is in your list of words, `x` will have to be compared to every element of the list.

Instead you can use a `set` to speed up the process, as it has constant time lookup*. Try the following:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
nltk.download('words')
gibberishBody = []
my_words = set(words.words())
for x in bodyStopWords:
    if x in my_words:
        gibberishBody.append(x)
print(gibberishBody)
```

* technically the constant time is only in expectation, but that's good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

When testing I get this output:
`code`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-b1a75f648ba4> in <module>
      8 
      9 for x in bodyPre:
---> 10     if x in my_words:
     11         gibberishBody.append(x)
     12 print(gibberishBody)
`code`

Comment: I'm afraid in this formatting I'm not sure what the error is. Note however that the code as-is is not runable, as `bodyStopWords` is undefined.

Comment: Perhaps bodyStopWords is a list of lists? In that case, this will not work as lists cannot be hashed and therefore cannot be used for lookup in a set (because a python `set` is a hashtable).

Answer (score 0):

This might improve matters. words.words() returns a list. That list *may* have to be constructed every time the *words()* function is called. Nonetheless, using the *in* keyword on a list is considerably slower than when used against a set. Given that all the words in the list are unique, you could rearrange your code as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
from pandas import DataFrame
import random
import time

WL = words.words() # get the word list
print(f'Word list contains {len(WL)} words')
WS = set(WL) # convert to a set
NW = min(20_000, len(WL)) # not really necessary as the word list is known to contain over 200k words
bodyStopWords = DataFrame([random.choice(WL) for _ in range(NW)])[0] # get a Series representation
print(f'{NW} random stopwords chosen')
s = time.perf_counter() # note start time
gibberishBody = [x for x in bodyStopWords if x in WS] # build the body
e = time.perf_counter() # note end time
print(f'{e-s:.4f}s')
```

This is a re-write of my original answer to include a pandas Series and demonstrate performance characteristics. On my machine the *gibberishBody* list is constructed in 0.0051s

Comment: Thanks for response!
`code`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-c6ae0c38c68e> in <module>
      8 W = set(words.words())
      9 
---> 10 gibberishBody = [x for x in bodyPre if x in W]
     11 
     12 print(gibberishBody)

<ipython-input-31-c6ae0c38c68e> in <listcomp>(.0)
      8 W = set(words.words())
      9 
---> 10 gibberishBody = [x for x in bodyPre if x in W]
     11 
     12 print(gibberishBody)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
`code`

Comment: This code will work perfectly in Python 3.9.9 providing *bodyStopWords* is an in-scope iterable. Obviously it can't run *as is* but neither can the code you presented in your question!